# Stripping list into 3 columns Problem. BeautifulSoup, Requests, Pandas, Itertools

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-itertools

Python novice back again!  I got a lot of great help on this but am now stumped.  The code below scrapes soccer match data and scores from Lehigh University soccer website.  I am trying to split the scores format ['T', '0-0(2 OT)'] into 3 columns 'T', '0-0, '2 OT but I am running into problems.  The issue lies in this part of the code:

=> for result in soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'sidearm-schedule-game-result'}):
=> result = result.get_text(strip=True).split(',')

I tried .split(',') but that did not work as it created ['T', '0-0(2 OT)'].  Is there a way to split than into 3 columns 1) T, 2) 0-0 and 3) 2 OT???

All help much appreciated. 
Thanks

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    from itertools import zip_longest

    d = []
    n = []
    res = []
    op = []
    yr = []
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for year in range(2003, 2020):
            print(f"Extracting Year# {year}")
            r = req.get(
                f"https://lehighsports.com/sports/mens-soccer/schedule/{year}")
            if r.status_code == 200:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
                for date in soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'sidearm-schedule-game-opponent-date flex-item-1'}):
                    d.append(date.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))
                for name in soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'sidearm-schedule-game-opponent-name'}):
                    n.append(name.get_text(strip=True))
                for result in soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'sidearm-schedule-game-result'}):
                    result = result.get_text(strip=True)
                    #result = result.get_text(strip=True).split(',')
                    res.append(result)
                if len(d) != len(res):
                    res.append("None")
                for opp in soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'sidearm-schedule-game-opponent-text'}):
                    op.append(opp.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
                    yr.append(year)


    data = []
    for items in zip_longest(yr, d, n, op, res):
        data.append(items)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Year', 'Date', 'Name', 'opponent', 'Result']).to_excel('lehigh.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: you're splitting on `,` but the second item is not delimited by a `,`. you have two options, split the second item by parens and remove the trailing parens or use regex to parse it

Comment: its not always a parenthesis sometimes there is no parenthesis.  Also, I am not good at regex (python generally but working on it!).

Comment: I tried 2-3 random years in your range and didn't run across anything like `'T', '0-0(2 OT)'`; I did see things like `'W,2-1OT'` and `'T,2-2Game called after first overtime due to lightning'`; everything else has this format `'W,2-0'`. So into what  would you split these?

Comment: Hi Jack
trying to split those into 3 columns, so your example above: 'W, 2-1OT" split into W, 2-1, and OT.  In the other example, 'T, 2-2Game called after first overtime due to lightning' split into T, 2-2, and " Game called after first overtime due to lightning.  Thanks Jack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to focus here only on splitting the `res` list into three columns, and you can incorporate it into your code as you see fit. So let's say you have this:

```
res1='T, 0-0(2 OT)'
res2='W,2-1OT' 
res3='T,2-2Game called '
res4='W,2-0'
scores = [res1,res2,res3,res4]
```

We split them like this:

```
print("result","score","extra")
for score in scores:
    n_str = score.split(',')
    target = n_str[1].strip()        
    print(n_str[0].strip(),'    ',target[:3],' ',target[3:])
```

Output:

```
result score extra
T      0-0   (2 OT)
W      2-1   OT
T      2-2   Game called
W      2-0
```

Note that this assumes that no game ends with double digits scores (say, 11-2, or whatever); so this should work for your typical soccer game, but will fail with basketball :D